# How do I get my Links under my Links label?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a tile, and inside it I have a Links div along with actual links.

I want my **Result** to be LINKS and then the Hypterlinks under in a column.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<div class="tile">
    <div class="first">
        <b>Links</b>
    </div>
    <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Phone List" runat="server"/> 
    <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink2" NavigateUrl="#" Text="FAQ" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```css
.first {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:10%;
}
.tile {
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 14px;
    border-width: 3px;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 130px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 270px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #CCF11B), color-stop(1, #3874FF));
    background-image: linear-gradient(-28deg, #CCF11B 0%, #3874FF 100%);
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add a

```
<br>
```

after your first div.
then contain your links into another div with a class give it any name here I named it links.

```
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="first"><b>Links</b></div>
    <br>
    <div class="links">
    <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Phone List" runat="server"/> 
    <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink2" NavigateUrl="#" Text="FAQ" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and add to your css the following code:

```
.links{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```